# How to automatically copy data entry from 1 workbook into another without having to activate macro or open workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have come across a problem while trying to do the following:

I have 2 workbooks 1 called Master and the other one called Slave. Master has a worksheet called Data where data is inputted into it automatically every so often. Data is inputted into cells ranging from A8 to BL8. Every time new data is stored, it pushes the old data downwards and saves it into again A8:BL8. Slave has a worksheet called DATA with the exact same format.

My goal is the following:

I want to write a VBA code where each time new data is inputted into(USUALLY 6-7 NEW DATA ENTRIES PER 24 HOURS) Master workbook(Worksheet called Data), I want it to update the same information onto the Slave workbook (worksheet called DATA) without having to even open or run the workbook(Data can be inputted at random times throughout the day so I am not always around to keep track and need it to transfer data on its own).

Both workbooks are saved in different locations on my computer. My attempt worked, however I was only able to get it to work with copying the current values in the cell range A8:BL8 and moving it over to the workbook I want by triggering the macro with a button(inserting)... (I hope my problem is clear) so it only updates the very latest data and not ALL the data.

My goal eventually is to be able to do this between many workbooks with the same format (into the same workbook Slave(worksheet DATA))

My Code runs from workbook Slave (worksheet DATA) via a button assigned to this macro.

```
Sub OpenCopyPaste()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim Reportwb As Workbook
    Set Reportwb = Workbooks("Slave.xlsm")
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\yilmadu001          \Desktop\Master.xlsm")
    wb.Sheets("Data").Range("A8:BL8").Copy
    Reportwb.Sheets("DATA").Range("A8:BL8").Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Reportwb.Save
    wb.Close False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Just so I'm clear, you want to edit the contents of another excel file without opening it...?

Comment: I guess he means "without opening the file by clicking on it on the windows UI"

Comment: *without having to activate macro or open workbook* - call Bill Gates and ask for the source code of Excel. Then hire a team of rock-star devs  and give them about 6 months. Then ping me, I wanna see the result as well! :)

Comment: Technically if you disable and enable screen updating you could open, edit, save and close a workbook without ever seeing it, but to trigger this on every cell change would make using your workbook a nightmare.

Comment: Assuming you mean that you want to automate a data transfer, rather than requiring manual steps... What's the trigger to copy data? It's going to get really slow and awkward if you open the target workbook, copy data to it, then close it again after every single cell changes...

Comment: @TimWilkinson without physically opening the workbook...... obviously the workbooks will be opened and closed within the macro . My point was I do not want to open up my workbook every time I want to update these values and am wondering if there is a way this macro can be triggered on its own every time there is a cell change in the Master workbook so it runs on its own without me having to trigger it.

Comment: @Olly currently its assigned to a button which is exactly my main problem because I have to trigger it physically and it is not automated

Comment: @DYilm ① This macro needs no run in the master workbook to trigger anything. ② If you open/update/close on every cell change this will slow you down to un-usable.

Comment: @DYilm In that case the answer to your question is yes, but I wouldn't advise it as it would make your workbook almost unusable. You would be better off doing it manually like you have now, or catch the onsave or beforeclose events.

Comment: @Jeeped you are absolutely right, I have edited my post now to attach my code, that is my last intension just looking for some help or a better way of achieving my goal :)

Comment: @TimWilkinson that is a very good idea (to get it to catch onsave events). The workbook has an autosave macro so after each entry there is an autosave. How can i link my code to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your comment, to run your code before save put the following into the `ThisWorkbook` object.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim Reportwb As Workbook
    Set Reportwb = Workbooks("Slave.xlsm")
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\yilmadu001          \Desktop\Master.xlsm")
    wb.Sheets("Data").Range("A8:BL8").Copy
    Reportwb.Sheets("DATA").Range("A8:BL8").Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Reportwb.Save
    wb.Close False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```